# Stetic GUI Designer Move to Glade for Gtk#3

Tags: c#, user-interface, gtk#, glade

I'm currently working at an audiobackend binding for my application. Since I want to use gstreamer, I found out, that I need to use GTK#3, because this is needed by gstreamer-sharp. Since I'm currently working with monodevelop, which uses stetic for GUI design, I wanted to ask, what is the best way, moving towards GTK#3. I see, that it uses .ui files for GUI definition, which can be generated by glade (I also tried a little bit around with glade). But my application has 4 windows with much code, so how can I easily transport this to GTK#3? Has anybody done this already?

Greeting
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkBuilder works for both GTK2 and GTK3, Smuxi will eventually go that route and backport the GtkBuilder converted .ui files from Stetic back to GTK2.

The tool to convert the existing stetic UIs can be found here:
https://github.com/xDarkice/stetic2ui

Comment: Thanks for the help, with this tool I could move to GTk#3 :).

Answer (score 1):

[Smuxi](https://github.com/meebey/smuxi) was a GTK2 app made with stetic too. When we did a Gnome .NET hackfest recently in Austria they found the problems you are talking about, but eventually solved them by using glade files and some clever approach to still be compatible with GTK2 and GTK3 at the same time, so you might want to look at their commits from September to November of 2013.

Comment: I see you are working with compiler constants, but this seems a bit hard to keep 2 Versions of the project. Maybe this is the only possibility, bit moving towards GTK#3 seems to be a bit more work than I expected ;).

Comment: blame the gtk+ maintainers! gtk-sharp is just a binding, and the only breaking changes we did are using "I" prefixes for interfaces, and not many things more

Comment: I'm not blaiming, since I welcome the work all of the maintainers did and will do ;). I just thought moving to GTK#3 would be less work, but thats ok ;).